# How to retieve value from parent to child table in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate, I have two table named as `Employeedetails` and `Leaverecord` in this Employeedetails is a parent and Leaverecord as child. A employee can take multiple leave, i want to get a leave record of particular employee.
[image]

Mu query is,

```
select a.leaverecords.leaveFrom from Employeedetails as a,Leaverecord as b where b.employeedetails.refId='1017'
```

but it throws error like,
`illegal attempt to dereference a collection`

My `Employeedetails.hbm.xml`

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="pojo.Employeedetails" table="employeedetails" catalog="hrm">
    <id name="refId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="RefId" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <set name="leaverecords" table="leaverecord" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="RefId" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="pojo.Leaverecord" />
    </set>
 </class>
```

my `Leaverecord.hbm.xml`

```
<class name="pojo.Leaverecord" table="leaverecord" catalog="hrm">
    <id name="sno" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="Sno" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="employeedetails" class="pojo.Employeedetails" fetch="select">
        <column name="RefId" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="leaveFrom" type="date">
        <column name="LeaveFrom" length="10" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="leaveTo" type="date">
        <column name="LeaveTo" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="empReason" type="string">
        <column name="EmpReason" length="100" not-null="true" />
    </property>
</class>
```

Comment: you would need to define the mappings either through xml or annotations. Where Refid would be the connecting field so we have the join column annotation present, and relationship as many to one, or one to many

Comment: ya i am adding mapping through xml.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
   select b.`leave From` from Employeedetails as a
   inner join Leaverecord as b on a.RefId = b.RefId
   where a.refId='1017'
```

you have `leave From` column and not `leaveFrom` .

Comment: ya correct, but i want to put employeedetails as main.

Comment: i need to access child table values from parent table like `a.leaverecords.leaveFrom` not `b.leaveFrom`